# Php templating - Getting the html right

Tags: php, html, oop, templating

I'm developing a web app and I'm having a problem with the templating fase. The problem concerns the generation o html code in a php object. The code is as follows:

```
<?php class abcHtml {
    function prepare() { ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <?php echo $this->meta; ?>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="bg">
            <div id="container_wrapper">
                <?php echo $this->cont; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>

<?php }} ?>
```

The goal is to have a php file with the cleanest html code possible(Don't want to use any framework).

```
<?php

class abc extends abcHtml
{
    protected $meta;
    protected $cont;

    public function render(){
        return parent::prepare();
    }

    public function setMeta($meta){
        $this->meta = $meta;
        return $this;
}

?>
```

This class inherites abcHtml to make possible to add diferent html modules. The problem is that when calling render(), the returned html code is note in the right order, the html code in the $meta and $cont variables appear before the html that is inside the prepare function.

For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/base_style.css"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="bg">
            <div id="container_wrapper">
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

This problem obviously means that php is running the php code first and then attaching the html. Is there a solution to fix this?

Comment: A solution could be: Use twig, smarty or dwoo!

Comment: You might benefit from [**this article**](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html). It explains one of approaches for implementing templates with native PHP.

Comment: Thanks tereško, the ob_start() function helped a lot. Don't know about performance though.

Comment: Unless you are making multi-megabyte HTML files, performance shouldn't be an issue, because the `ob_*` functions are just exposing the way how PHP handles output all along.